# Tela branca em transição entre activities

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

Tenho um projeto no qual desenvolvi um método para salvar uma referência da `activity` atual e quando eu utilizasse o `HOME` da próxima tela, ele retornasse para a `activity` utilizando essa referência salva.

Porém quando aperto para voltar, a tela fica totalmente branca e logo segue o fluxo desejado. Esse problema só ocorre em versões android 8.0 +.

Segue o `OnOptionsItemsSelected` criado:

```
case Android.Resource.Id.Home:
                DroidApplication.current.navigation.StartActivity(ownerActivity, DroidApplication.current.CurrentTypeActivity);
                return true;

                default:
                return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

Segue o `StartActivity`:

```
 public void StartActivity(Activity activity, Type activityDestino, Dictionary<string, object> prefs)
    {
        StartActivity(activity, new Intent(activity, activityDestino), prefs);
    }

    public void StartActivity(Activity activity, Type activityDestino)
    {
        StartActivity(activity, new Intent(activity, activityDestino), null);
    }

    public void StartActivity(Activity activity, Intent intent, Dictionary<string, object> prefs)
    {
        int animationIn = Resource.Animation.fade_in;
        int animationOut = Resource.Animation.fade_out;

        StartActivity( activity, intent, animationIn, animationOut, prefs);
    }

    public void StartActivity(Activity activity, Intent intent, int animationIn, int animationOut, Dictionary<string, object> prefs)
    {
        SavePreferences(activity, prefs);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NoAnimation);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        activity.StartActivity(intent);
        //activity.OverridePendingTransition(animationIn, animationOut);
    }
```

Quando eu *starto* uma `activity`, não ocorre nenhum problema e eu utilizo o mesmo método:

Exemplo:

```
else if (codigoAcao == CODIGO_ACAO_ACTIVITY_MAIN)
        {
            DroidApplication.retornarInicial = false;
            StartActivity(activity, typeof(MainActivity));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver meu problema...

Quando eu utilizava isso:

```
 intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NoAnimation);
 intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
```

Toda a pilha de activities era limpada. Isso fazia com que minhas referências ficassem perdidas e quando eu retornava para a activity, eu teria que recarregá-la... Esse tempo de criação da tela ficava branco e só depois o layout aparecia... 
Então a solução foi retirar essas linhas de código que foi resolvido.

Comment: Só precisa remover isso intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTop); a Flag NoAnimation não precisa remover.